# How do you write the taylor series for (arctan(x))^2

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I know that the taylor series of $\arctan{(x)}$ is $x - \frac{x^3}3 + \frac{x^5}5 + \dotsc$

In order to square it I would have to multiply it by itself.

$(x - \frac{x^3}3 + \frac{x^5}5 + \dotsc) \cdot (x - \frac{x^3}3 + \frac{x^5}5 + \dotsc)$

How do I multiply the first 3 terms of that?

Comment: You may want to see [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Answer (score 2):

If you are just interested in the coefficients, the answers above will be sufficient. But if you are interested in more compact form, or you need this in your homework, you may like to see this.

You could obtain beautiful representation of this series, using just a few tricks.

First write down the form after applying convolution.

$$\arctan^2x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k {1 \over {2k+1}} (-1)^{n-1-k} {1 \over {2(n-1-k)+1}}$$
..the coefficient can be manipulated this way..

$$(-1)^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {1 \over {2k+1}} \cdot {1 \over {2(n-1-k)+1}}$$

then
$$(-1)^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left({1 \over {2k+1}} + {1 \over {2(n-1-k)+1}}\right) \cdot {1 \over {2n}}$$

using the fact that ${1 \over {2k+1}} \cdot {1 \over {2(n-1-k)+1}} = \left({1 \over {2k+1}} + {1 \over {2(n-1-k)+1}}\right) \cdot {1 \over {2n}}$.

You'll find that the summation will meet every element of $\{1, 1/3, 1/5, ..., 1/(2n-1)\}$ **exactly twice**. This helps you go further:

$$(-1)^{n-1} {1 \over {2n}} \cdot 2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {1 \over {2k+1}} $$

So finally,

$$\arctan^2x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left((-1)^{n-1} {1 \over n} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {1 \over {2k+1}} \right) x^{2n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication of two polynomials is a convolution. Given that you are OK with truncating at some higher power, you could use Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) combined with the convolution theorem, turning the convolution into a pointwise product of Fourier coefficients. This reduces the computational load from $$\mathcal{O}(n^2) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(n\log(n))$$

Answer (score 0):

First let's reduce the power to something we know
$$\frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1}(x)^2 = \frac{2 \tan^{-1}(x)}{x^2+1}$$
Then let's find the series for this
$$\frac{2 \tan^{-1}(x)}{x^2+1} = 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{1+2k}}{(1+2k)(x^2+1)}$$
We now have to reintegrate
$$2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+2}\,_2F_1(1, k+1, k+2, -x^2)}{4k^2+6k+2}$$
Not pretty, but it is a series representation without any higher powers

Answer (score 0):

If you need the infinite series, Brevan Ellefsen gave the answer.

If you need a truncated expansion, use, as you wrote, $$\tan^{-1}x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+O\left(x^9\right)$$ and multiply term by term to get $$\left(\tan^{-1}x\right)^2=x^2-\frac{2 x^4}{3}+\frac{23 x^6}{45}-\frac{44 x^8}{105}+O\left(x^9\right)$$ $$\left(\tan^{-1}x\right)^3=x^3-x^5+\frac{14 x^7}{15}-\frac{818 x^9}{945}+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$ and so on.